# How to start a new activity from another app while in kiosk mode?

Tags: android, android-intent, kiosk-mode

I have two apps that **both** have kiosk mode enabled. I currently send a broadcast from one to the other that transmits data. I want to tell the receiving app to start a new activity.

In most cases I would be able to use intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); however... I am not able to start a new task while in kiosk mode.

Here is what I have in the broadcastReceiver(which I have verified works for other data). This code tries to start a new activity:

```
            Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // this doesn't work in kiosk mode...
            launchIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("my.package","my.package.myactivity"));
            try {
                if(launchIntent != null) {
                    context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(launchIntent);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Started activity");
                } else
                    Log.i(TAG, "Intent is null");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
```

My error before adding the flag:

```
Kiosk Mode: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

And after adding the flag:

```
E/ActivityManager(  470): Attempted Lock Task Mode violation
```

Is it possible to send a context through a broadcast receiver, perhaps, so that I can start the desired activity using that context? Can anyone suggest another method other than using broadcasts to start new activity?

Answer (score 3):

Note: In Android "ScreenPinning", "Kioskmode" and "Lock Task Mode" are the same.

from https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenPinning

```
Once your app activates screen pinning, users cannot (...) 
access other apps (...) until your app exits the mode.
```

You have to temprary disable the kioskmode with stopLockTask() interact and re-enable it with startLockTask()

To prevent android from asking the user to re-start kioskmode you also need to implement a https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#DeviceOwner app

You can find a lot of infos about this topic at https://github.com/Tuong-Nguyen/Android/wiki/Research-114-Kiosk-Mode-Android-application